# How to replace all subsets of values in a PyTorch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

Let's say I have two PyTorch tensors:

```
t_1d = torch.Tensor([9, 3, 0, 3, 5, 7, 3, 3, 5, 3, 1, 11]])
t = torch.Tensor([3, 5])
t_replace = torch.Tensor([10, 8])
```

I want to replace all occurrences of the second tensor `t` in `t_1d` with the new tensor `t_replace`.

The output should be something like:

```
torch.Tensor([9, 3, 0, 10, 8, 7, 3, 10, 8, 3, 1, 11]])
```

Preferably on GPU for large Tensors, so no loops or Numpy casts.

Comment: What would you expect the output to be if `t_1d = [1, 1, 1]`, `t  =  [1, 1]`, and `t_replace = [2, 2]`?

Comment: An arbitrary one, for example `[1, 2, 2]` or `[2, 2, 1]` are both correct solutions. But in the case of `t_1d = [1, 1, 1, 1]` we want `[2, 2, 2, 2]` and NOT `[1, 2, 2, 1]`. Analogously for a higher number of equal subsequent integers we want the maximum number of replacements to be executed.